# How can I change the pathway of a file that is currently saving "ThisWorkbook.Path"?

Tags: excel, vba

The file I am trying to save is currently saving under "ThisWorkbook.Path" but I would like to specifically define the pathway.

I have tried defining the pathway with "ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename: ..."

This is the entire section of code with the code I tried disabled and above the line I'm trying to modify.

```
' Save CSV Files
Dim myCSVFileName As String
Dim tempWB As Workbook

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

'myCSVFileName = ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename= "S:\shared\6. Distributions\10) epMotion\Buffer and Sample CSVs\" & "\" & "Sample CSV" & VBA.Format(VBA.Now, "_mm-dd-yyyy hh-mm") & ".csv"


myCSVFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path = "S:\shared\6. Distributions\10) epMotion\Buffer and Sample CSVs\" & "\" & "Sample CSV" & VBA.Format(VBA.Now, "_mm-dd-yyyy hh-mm") & ".csv"

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sample CSV").Activate
ActiveSheet.Copy
Set tempWB = ActiveWorkbook

With tempWB
.SaveAs Filename:=myCSVFileName, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
.Close
End With
```

It seems like it should be a pretty straight forward tweak but I'm not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: Remove this bit `ThisWorkbook.Path = ` so it's just `myCSVFileName = "S:...`

Comment: The `=` operator is dual-purposed in VBA. In `myCSVFilename = something` it's an *assignment* operator. In `If foo = bar` it's a *comparison* operator. If you place a breakpoint after the `myCSVFilename` assignment, you'll find that the string contains the value `False`... you're assigning to the result of a comparison, which is a Boolean.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You are already declaring the path

Your file name should read

```
myCSVFileName = "S:\shared\6. Distributions\10) epMotion\Buffer and Sample CSVs\" & "\" & "Sample CSV" & VBA.Format(VBA.Now, "_mm-dd-yyyy hh-mm") & ".csv"
```